# Delete some key of object to Query to MongoDB with null value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

First of all, I apologize for my weakness English and thank you to anyone for suggested to me.

I would like to made a software for stock management which one requirement is it can create a new category of equipment to application with realtime(this one mean to in each category, their attributes will be difference).

e.g.

**Table of computer notebook**

---

| id | cpu_type | brand | cpu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I7 | Lenovo | 10750H |
| 2 | I5 | HP | 10510U |

---

Table of Smartphone

---

| id | brand | tec_support | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Samsung | 5G | xxl-23132 |
| 2 | xxxxxx | 4G | abc-2310s |

It make me confused because I have only basic in ORM,I don't know how to auto generate model and migrate the database. Then I found NoSQL and I thought it can help me for this project.

Week ago, I learned about "query with NoSQL" and then I choose the MongoDB.
I have found problem as when I query with null (my template/key has a null value )
and I  fix it with solution. (show as my code below, I deleted the key which contain null )

```
 // service name find for find equipment

exports.find = async (queryItem) => { 
    await client.connect()
    const db = client.db(dbName)
    const collection = db.collection('equipment')
    let {category, price, color} = queryItem

    // prepare my query item in to variable 
    const item = {
        category: category? category: null,
        "detail.price": price? {"$gt": 1000}: null,
        "detail.color": color? {"$regex": color}: null
    }

    // filter if key is not a value (has a null) I will delete it 
    for (const k in item){
        if(item[k] === null) delete item[k]
    }
    
    const result = await collection.find(item).toArray()
    await client.close()
    return result
}
```

// my data in database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612270128edcff193fad921c"),
    "category" : "computer_nb",
    "detail" : {
        "price" : 500,
        "color" : "red"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61246b7942785ac200accce5"),
    "category" : "computer_nb",
    "detail" : {
        "price" : 2500,
        "color" : "blue"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61246b8a42785ac200accce6"),
    "category" : "computer_nb",
    "detail" : {
        "price" : 2500,
        "color" : "red"
    }
}
```

// my json request

```
{
    "category":"computer_nb",
    "color": "d"
}
```

// my response result

```
  {
    "_id": "61246b7942785ac200accce5",
    "category": "computer_nb",
    "detail": {
      "price": 2500,
      "color": "blue"
    }
  }
```

My code is working fine but I have questions to ask.

Is my solution correct? (correct is mean to appropriate, performance) and How can I make it better than?